# How to get arguments in a flat way with withLatestFrom in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Is it possible to get the arguments of `tap` function not nested? like some of those ways:

```
tap(([foo, bar, baz]) => {

or:
tap((foo, bar, baz) => {

or:
tap(({foo, bar, baz}) => {
```

Because I using `withLatestFrom` which give me array and I pass an object into `Subject` so I wondering if its possible to get the arguments in flat way?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fj48u6?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

```
import { of, map, Observable, Subject, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';

const action = new Subject<{ foo: number; bar: number }>();

const baz$ = of(3);

const op = action.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(baz$),
  tap(([{ foo, bar }, baz]) => {
    console.log({ foo, bar, baz });
  })
);

op.subscribe();

action.next({ foo: 1, bar: 2 });
```

Comment: I do not know how you would go about flattening an object (eg. `{ foo: 1, bar: 2 }`) with an array like `[1, 2, 3]`? But you could in any case do something like `tap(([obj, arr]) => { ... }` where `obj` is the emission from the `Subject` and `arr` is the emission from the observable in `withLatestFrom`. Do you still find it inelegant?

Comment: not sure. because I try to do `tap((...args) => args)` - not works. the idea is to be transparent to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom operator to flatten object to array

```
const transformToArray = source=>source.pipe(map((values:any)=>{
  return values.map(v=>v instanceof Object?Object.values(v):v).flat()
}
))
const op = action.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(baz$),
  transformToArray
);
```